# Why is there no `classListNS` similar to `setAttributeNS`?

Tags: javascript, dom, namespaces

I asked about if `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS` are necessary from a logical view point today. Everyone seems to think that `createElementNS` is needed. I might agree on that (but it could be changed).

No one commented on `setAttributeNS` which is actually the more interesting part. Thinking about that again I realize that there is no `classListNS`. So I guess everyone agrees that this is not needed. Why is `classListNS` not needed (while `setAttributeNS` maybe is - for some reason I do not understand)?

Comment: Classes are an HTML thing and they don’t have a namespace.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Is not attributes also an HTML thing?

Comment: No, attributes exist in all SGML derivatives, e.g. XML, SVG, HTML.

Comment: Because CSS is not namespaced?

Comment: _classes_ are not namespaced.

Comment: @epascarello Well, CSS does have [namespace selectors](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) specifically for namespaced elements.

Comment: @SebastianSimon but the class names are not which is what classList will add. Missed "class" in my comment :)

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea about "namespace selectors". But does all this mean I can set an attribute from a different namespace on the element than that the element belongs too?